# Custom CDI scope in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, thorntail

How can I create a custom CDI scope in Quarkus? I need to create a bean with a scope that lives during the whole http request of a rest endpoint. This is exactly how the ConversationScoped works in a Thorntail application. Since it is not implemented in Quarkus, I need to create one. The section 6.11 of the CDI guide is very succinct on how to create a custom context. It does not mention which dependency is necessary for the BuildStep annotation for example.

Comment: "I need to create a bean with a scope that lives during the whole http request of a rest endpoint." The request scope is exactly that. Creating custom scope is probably overkill, better to figure out why request scope doesn't work for you, because it should.

Comment: I don't think that request scope means that. It means that a new bean is inject at every request to it, not every request in the same http request.

Comment: "It means that a new bean is inject at every request to it" -- that's not `@RequestScoped`, that's `@Dependent`. `@RequestScoped` is tied to an HTTP request.

Comment: I created a very simple quarkus application at https://github.com/AmsterdamFilho/quarkus-poc just to show it is not like that. I tested with both 1.2.1.Final and the current version from master.

Comment: Actually, you are right. RequestScoped means exactly what you said. The problem is that the class had a produce method, that also required to be annotated as RequestScoped.